# Is there an OR combinator in jQuery/Sizzle?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, sizzle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery OR Selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263975/jquery-or-selector)

I would like to for each `select` in the matched set find the first `option` that either has a class `placeholder` or an empty value something along the lines of

```
$(selectorOrJquery).find('select').andSelf().filter('select')
  .find('(option.placeholder OR option[value=""]):first)
```

That is unfortunately not a valid sizzle (or CSS3) syntax - anyone know if there is a valid way to do this with selectors?

Obviously I could write procedural code to find this for me, but I'm hoping for something a bit more slick

**Edit:**
To clarify, I do not think a comma simply works. Imagine the following

```
<select>
  <option class="placeholder" value="0">Select Something</option>
  <option value="">Legitimate option that gets handled in JS</value>
</select>
```

In this case I want only the first selected, NOT both

Comment: I answered this way back when.

Comment: Oh boy.  I simply can't decide who has the most valid answer here :)

Comment: @DanielA.White Would that really preserve the order of prescendence of operations though? What if a single select contains a .placeholder followed by a [value=""] - I believe comma syntax will select both and I wont only the first matched to either

Answer (score 4):

I have also run into an issue like this in the past and settled for something like this.

```
$(selectorOrJquery).find('select').andSelf().filter('select')
  .find('option.placeholder, option[value=""]').eq(0);
```

Comment: Yeah, but what if there's multiple select elements? Gotta use an each

Comment: The eq(0) selects a single element.

Answer (score 1):

This will return the first option of a select that is either empty or has a class placeholder.

```
$("select option:first").filter(":empty,.placeholder")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a comma, which is a valid CSS/jQuery Selector.

```
$(selectorOrJquery).find('select').andSelf().filter('select')
  .find('(option.placeholder,  option[value=""]):first)
```

Answer (score 1):

the css OR is the comma, so the selector you want would be

```
'option.placeholder:first, option[value=""]:first'
```

Comment: the answer of @John Kalberer is the one that solves your case