# How to combine two filters in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery 1.6.2

I am trying to turn the first and last cells of a table yellow.

Basically, I am using two lines of code to accomplish this.

```
$("tr:first").children("td:first").css("background", "yellow");
$("tr:first").children("td:last").css("background", "yellow");
```

How can I combine the two filters together to get the first and last tds in a row?

Comment: I think you are looking for the `or selector`.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263975/jquery-or-selector

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("tr:first").children("td:first, td:last").css("background", "yellow");
```

Comment: Yep, you should just think about how you would do it in regular css ;)

Comment: Yes, I SHOULD think about that. I wish I actually did that more often than I do.  Thanks!

Comment: I actually missed it myself the first time I had to do something similar. So no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can use multiple selectors at once by separating them with a comma:

```
$("tr:first").children("td:first, td:last").css("background", "yellow");
```

Here is the jQuery documentation for "Multiple Selectors": http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

For a general note, jQuery uses the Sizzle Selction Engine which bases it's syntax off of CSS syntax ( http://sizzlejs.com/ ).

Comment: It seems that I forget about this too frequently.  This is perfect. Thanks!