# Select element by class or ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am working on an ASP.NET page in which I generate some JavaScript code based on values in a database.

For example, in the database there might be the formula `sum([#itemA])`, which would evaluate to something like `$('#itemA').change(function(){ sum(this); });`.

I know that I can select elements using jQuery selectors such as `$('[id*=itemA]')` or `$('[class*=itemA]')`, but I am wondering if there is any way to combine these selectors so that any element with either a class *or* an ID of `itemA` would be selected.

Right now in my code I am just using `if/else` blocks to deal with ID's or classes, but if there is an easier implementation, I would love to use it.

I looked at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and googled around a bit, but I didn't see anything that answered my question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263975/jquery-or-selector

Comment: That will work. I totally forgot CSS selectors were applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
$('[id*=itemA], [class*=itemA]')
```

For more details, take a look to [official jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: This is the correct answer. OP is looking for either class OR id. Not class within an id.

Comment: This is perfect. I've been so focused on the Javascript so much that I totally forgot to think in terms of CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple selectors like

```
    $('.class1, .class2....., .classn')
```

You can literally use anything like ID names, class names or selectors like you specified separated by commas

Answer (score 0):

Like in css, when selectors are separated by `,`they are cumulated :

```
var elements = $('[id*=itemA], [class*=itemA]')
```

Comment: This will not work, it will select only [class*=itemA] that are in [id*=itemA]

Comment: Yeah I miss the comma