# How to use "or" and "and" operators in "value" field of css selector in json

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the below code i want "or" "and" operator in the value field
so that i dont have to write a new step everytime if i found diff css-selectors pointing to same location.
And thanks in Advance

```
{
  "name": "cardAccount.accountHolder",
  "locator": {
      "locatorType": "BY_CSSSELECTOR",
      "value": "#login>div>b || #login>span"

  }
```

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate because of the context in which this answer is in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263975/jquery-or-selector/2263976#2263976

Answer (score 2):

Use a comma, it is like a strict OR, not an exclusive OR.

```
#login>div>b, #login>span
```

AND doesn't really work except by just being more explicit with the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Daniel A. White said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24849625/1816580) the comma is an implicit *OR* operator. It can only be used at the highest level meaning you can only concatenate two or more full selectors using the comma. Something like this XPath expression `//*[@class or @id]` cannot be achieved with CSS selectors.

The *AND* operator is implicit. If you want a div to have `class1` and `class2` you write `div.class1.class2`. This means that *AND* only works on a single level. If you want to have

`.class1 > .class3` *AND* `.class2 > .class3`

then you would get `.class1.class2 > .class3`.

But what would it mean to have `.class1 > .class3` *AND* `.class2 > .class4`? It is entirely ambiguous and cannot be solved with CSS selectors, because it doesn't make sense.