# how to add multiple "actual" element objects in JQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

I am working on Google Apps Script and using JQuery. I want to put multiple actual elements in the JQuery selector. I want to put **actual** elements in the selector.

I want:

```
$(kojiNameElem, tankaElem, suryoElem, unitElem)
```

not like(it works though):

```
$(".kojiName, .tanka, .suryo, .unit")
```

Please see this code followed:

```
var kojiNameElem = $("#koji_"+koji_id).find(".kojiName");
  var tankaElem = $("#koji_"+koji_id).find(".tanka");
  var suryoElem = $("#koji_"+koji_id).find(".suryo");
  var unitElem = $("#koji_"+koji_id).find(".unit");

  $(kojiNameElem, tankaElem, suryoElem, unitElem).on("focusin",function(e) {
    console.log("focusin");
  });
```

It works only on `kojiNameElem`. The other elements don't.

I know it works with one single element in the JQuery selector as below.

```
$(kojiNameElem).on("focusin",function(e) {
        console.log("focusin");
      });
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery OR Selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263975/jquery-or-selector)

Comment: @Nick the result is the same as my expectation but it is not answer exactly to my question. we don't have the way to put multiple actual elements directly in the JQuery selector as single actual element can be put in JQuery selector?

Comment: @Nick that's not the same question as that uses a string selector, but OP here wants to use objects and already demonstrates knowledge of `,` in strings

Comment: @freedomn-m the second answer to that question says specifically "Using a comma may not be sufficient if you have multiple jQuery **objects** that need to be joined."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to combine multiple jquery objects in a *single* selector - the method to do this is [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/)

Demonstration:

```js
var a = $("#a");
var b = $("#b");
var c = $("#c");

var arr = a.add(b).add(c).map((i, e)=>$(e).text()).toArray();
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted to know. "There's no way to combine multiple jquery objects in a single selector". and we can use add method instead. This answer is more straightforward to my OP so checked this as the accepted answer. thak you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like

```js
var koji_id=1;
  var kojiNameElem = $("#koji_"+koji_id).find(".kojiName");
  var tankaElem = $("#koji_"+koji_id).find(".tanka");
  var suryoElem = $("#koji_"+koji_id).find(".suryo");
  var unitElem = $("#koji_"+koji_id).find(".unit");

  $("#koji_"+koji_id).on("click", '.kojiName,.tanka,.suryo,.unit',function(e) {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="koji_1">
  <span class="kojiName">kojiName</span>
  <span class="tanka">tanka</span>
  <span class="suryo">suryo</span>
  <span class="unit">unit</span>
</div>
```

You can also use add method

```js
  var koji_id=1
  var koji= $("#koji_"+koji_id);
  var kojiNameElem = koji.find(".kojiName");
  var tankaElem = koji.find(".tanka");
  var suryoElem = koji.find(".suryo");
  var unitElem = koji.find(".unit");
  
  $(kojiNameElem).add(tankaElem).add(suryoElem).add(unitElem).on("click",function(e) {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="koji_1">
  <span class="kojiName">kojiName</span>
  <span class="tanka">tanka</span>
  <span class="suryo">suryo</span>
  <span class="unit">unit</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. It works. But we don't have the way to put multiple actual elements directly in the JQuery selector as single actual element can be put in JQuery selector?

Comment: Can you say what is your input? Is it array includes of class or something else ?

Comment: You may want add method as I added to answer @Helbert

Comment: Yes, add method fulfills my expectation. Thank you for your help! @pc_coder